# How to align center text or div item with Ant Design Space in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

How to align text or div item center horizontal with Space with Ant design ?
Here is my code:

```
import { Space } from 'antd'

<Space direction="horizontal" align="center" style={{width: '100%'}}>
  <span>Hello</span>
</Space>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because Antd uses flex for Space div, you need to use justifyContent.
Try this

```
<Space direction="horizontal" style={{width: '100%', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `direction="vertical"` with `align="center"`

```
import { Space } from 'antd'

<Space direction="vertical" align="center">
  <span>Hello</span>
</Space>
```